# How to replace indices with actual values?

Tags: r

Say I have the following data:

```
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
   [1,]  983  362  170  303  914  843  480  489  474   355
   [2,]  204  205  810  762  758  404   24  111  265   586
```

Each of these values corresponds to an index in another set called `labels`.  I would like to create the exact same structure as above, but instead of having the index, I want the value.

So far I have tried:

```
labels[attr(k,"nn.index")[1,]]
```

which returns `[1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2`, my desired result for the first row, and:

```
labels[attr(k,"nn.index")[2,]]
```

which returns `[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`, my desired result for the second row.

My problem is that if I try to do this for all rows I get the following results:

```
labels[attr(k,"nn.index")[1:2,]]
 [1] 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0 2 0
```

What would I have to change to get the result below?

```
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
   [1,]   2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
   [2,]   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Also, in real life there are thousands of rows, not just two.

Comment: `matrix(labels[attr(k,"nn.index")[1:2,]], nrow = 2)`

Comment: I probably should have specified that in real life there can be millions of rows.  I only showed two for simplicity sake.  Knowing this would your solution still work?

Comment: if you know the number of rows, yes, but heed @David Robinson

Comment: You would change it to `nrow=NROW(attr(k,"nn.index"))`, but I still like my solution better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do:

```
apply(attr(k,"nn.index"), 2, function(col) labels[col])
```

But didn't I give you this precise answer in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153255/how-to-view-the-nearest-neighbors-in-r)? (See the `closest.labels` variable).

Comment: You are right you did.  Sorry, I didn't make the connection until just now.

Comment: That's all right- cheers. A friendly word to the wise- I couldn't help but notice you've asked a lot of questions about every step of this project. You're a top contributor in several other tags: my guess is that if a newcomer in C# asked questions this densely, you'd suggest that if they spent more time trying to solve and understand the problem themselves, they'd learn the language faster. Again- just friendly advice!

Comment: You make an excellent point. I'll try to do a little more research next time. Been a while since I started from scratch with a new language.